# Creating a resolver to update dynamoDB item through AppSync - AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-appsync, amazon-dynamodb

So I created a resolver to create an item in the table using the below code.

```
const configSettingsDS = api.addDynamoDbDataSource('configSettingsDynamoTable', configurationSettingsTable);

    configSettingsDS.createResolver({
        typeName:'Mutation',
        fieldName: 'createConfigSettings',
        requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbPutItem(
            appsync.PrimaryKey.partition('id').auto(),
            appsync.Values.projecting('configSettings')),
        responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultItem(),
    });
```

I can't seem to find one to replicate the same thing on an update operation. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The update resolver works almost the same as the create resolver. In DynamoDB the operation for both is `PutItem`, so the same mapping template applies. You need to change the first parameter from `appsync.PrimaryKey.partion('id').auto()` to `appsync.PrimaryKey.partion('id').is('<PATH_TO_YOUR_ID>')`.

The id can be part of the object you pass as input. Though I prefer to have it separate, so the id is not part of the input object. Here is a very basic example for both variants.

**graphql schema:**

```
// Input A includes ID
input InputA {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}

// Input B does not include an ID
input InputB {
    name: String!
}

type Mutation {
    // Id is part of input
    updateA(input: InputA)

    // Id needs to be provided seperately
    updateB(id: ID!, InputB)
}
```

**resolver code:**

```js
// Configure the resolver where ID is part of the input
const resolverA = datasource.createResolver({
    typeName: `Mutation`,
    fieldName: `updateA`,
    requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbPutItem(
        appsync.PrimaryKey.partition('id').is('input.id'),
        appsync.Values.projecting('input'),
    ),
    responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultItem(),
});

// Configure the resolver where ID is provided as a separate input parameter.
const resolverB = datasource.createResolver({
    typeName: `Mutation`,
    fieldName: `updateB`,
    requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbPutItem(
        appsync.PrimaryKey.partition('id').is('id'),
        appsync.Values.projecting('input'),
    ),
    responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultItem(),
});
```

I just had to solve the same problem for my project. Here are some snippets on how I have set it up:

**Part of the graphql schema:**

```
input Label {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    imageUrl: String
}

input LabelInput {
    name: String!
    imageUrl: String
}

type Mutation {
    createLabel(input: LabelInput!): Label
    updateLabel(id: ID!, input: LabelInput!): Label
}
```

**Corresponding resolvers in cdk:**

```js
datasource.createResolver({
    typeName: `Mutation`,
    fieldName: `createLabel`,
    requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbPutItem(
        appsync.PrimaryKey.partition('id').auto(),
        appsync.Values.projecting('input'),
    ),
    responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultItem(),
});

datasource.createResolver({
    typeName: 'Mutation',
    fieldName: `updateLabel`,
    requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbPutItem(
        appsync.PrimaryKey.partition('id').is('id'),
        appsync.Values.projecting('input'),
    ),
    responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultItem(),
});
```

Comment: you're a lifesaver!!!

Comment: What if input contains a lot of fields and one needs to save it as an object without projecting. How would the mapping look like in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, DynamoDB provides an operation [*UpdateItem*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-updateitem). But CDK has not implemented it (at least what it seems to me).
My problem with `appsync.Values.projecting` is, if I don't know all fields in the table when executing a `PutItem`, I lose exsiting fields.